# Package not found in Python docx

Tags: python, docx

I can't find what I'm missing here. I'm just trying to open that document. It is at the same folder. It is a docx file. I just can't figure it out what's wrong here...

[image]

I don't even know what else to try...

Comment: It is not relevant if the file you try to open is in the same folder as your Python script. If you don't provide a path then `open` will try to open the file in the current working directory and that might be different.

Comment: If you always want to open the file from the same folder you can construct the absolute path to the file with `pathlib`: `import pathlib; path_to_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "your.filename"`

Comment: @Matthias I'm just trying to explore. This document is a model I just created to learn how to use the docx library. I have other test archives using the same structure and it's working (using only the name of the docx file since it is at the same folder).

Comment: I just created another folder and started a new python file and a new docx fila and it's working... That's crazy

Comment: Maybe your IDE has settings for the current directory and they are different from what you think.